# Admob Error only happening for one app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I have implemented admob banners into many iOS apps, and never had this problem. Now, using the same sdk version, same code, and a variety of IDs that currently work in other app projects, this one project gives the following output and does not display a banner:

```
To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
```

Why does it only happen in this Xcode project and how can I fix it? I'm not looking to find out how to enable testing mode. I want to get it to work just like all my other apps without testing mode.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always displays that message. It i letting you know that if you want test ads to set the testing id. If you are not getting a banner then something else is occurring. Perhaps you have no ad fill or have misconfigured the ad.

Comment: I looked in the other apps in which admob worked, and you're right, those apps logged that same thing. Once I knew that, I played around with the project that admob didn't show up in and found that for some reason the banner was showing up off screen even though the same code worked fine in  other projects.